# Creating a Mouselistner to Javafx rectangle

Tags: java, javafx, mouselistener

I want to create a mouselistner on my javafx rectangle.

the idea is that the rectangle has to change color when i press it?

Does anyone know how to add a listner to shapes in Javafx?

so far ive tried this:

```
    final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

        rect.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

However i get an error saying that

> the method setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler(){}) is
>   undefined for the type Rectangle

Abit more information:

The only options i have for rect are these:

```
rect.add()
rect.contains()
rect.grow();
rect.hashcode()
rect.intersection();
```

and a few others of no importance.

The import i am using are the following:

```
import com.sun.glass.events.MouseEvent;
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle;
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Shape;
```

Comment: It has various onMouse... properties;
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code looks correct and matches any examples I can find. To demonstrate this I have thrown together a quick example:

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100,100);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        rect.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                rect.setFill(Color.RED);
            }
        });


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

When the rectangle is clicked, the colour changes from blue to red.

This might be a long shot but make sure you are referencing the `Rectangle` type from the `JavaFX` library and not the `AWT` Rectangle i.e. make sure your import is:

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
```

and not

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

**Update**

As per my original comment it looks as though you are referencing the wrong import for the `Rectangle` type. I don't recognise the import `com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle`, is this from an older version of JavaFX?

You are also  referencing the incorrect `MouseEvent` type.

Change:

```
import com.sun.glass.events.MouseEvent;
```

To:

```
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this answer is quite old -- but as an update (Java 13, JavaFX 13):

```java
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
// ...
public void createRectangle() {

    Rectangle rect = new Rectanlge(200, 200);

    // On mouse click, code within here will be run.
    rect.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {

        // Read from another property to toggle
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);

    });

    // Add to scene in start()
}
```