# Coordinate location of cursor and colour change with certain condition - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Im starting to learn JavaFX. I have made a simple program that creates shapes.

I want to do basic events driven execution method, such as:

1. print the coordinate of the cursor if its inside a shape
2. changing the colour everytime the cursor enters a shape, then changing it back to the original once it is out of the shape

the following is what I have done

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;


public class ColouredShapes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        int radius = 40;
        int strokeWidth = 3;
        Color strokeColor = Color.BROWN;

        Circle circle1 = new Circle(250, 125, radius, Color.RED);
        circle1.setStroke(strokeColor);
        circle1.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        Rectangle square = new Rectangle(375, 85, 80, 80);
        square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        square.setStroke(strokeColor);
        square.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                50.0, 85.0,
               110.0, 60.0, 125.0, 175.0});

        polygon.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll(circle1, square, polygon);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250, Color.LIGHTYELLOW);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
    public static void maint(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create your shape, create an onEnter and onExit handler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359382/creating-a-mouselistner-to-javafx-rectangle. Instead of onMouseClicked use onMouseEntered and another OnMouseExited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add event mouse entered, exited, and moved handlers to the shape

```
square.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

  @Override
  public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {

      System.out.println(event.getScreenX());
      System.out.println(event.getScreenY());
    }
});
square.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

  @Override
  public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
    square.setFill(Color.GREEN);
  }
});
square.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

  @Override
  public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
    square.setFill(null);

  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153922/trying-to-add-menubar-as-node-to-a-scene-javafx